# GWT: RichTextArea getHTML loses "outer" tags

Tags: gwt

Please bear with me as I am a newbie in gwt and front end stuff.
I have a html string:

```
String s=
"<html><head><title>Hello World</title></head><body><b>Hello World</b></body></html>";
```

(I am using spaces in the tags to prevent the text from displaying "htmlized".)

```
//and gwt RichTextArea control->richTextArea

richTextArea.setHTML(s);
//So far so good as the document String displays as desired.

//Now comes the problem...
String transformed = richTextArea.getHTML();
```

The rich text area strips the outer and returns the inner html only. i.e. The body, html and the head tags are stripped.

Q How do I get the html string returned with only the modifications which occur in the rich text area showing.. i.e. The original "outer" tags do not get lost.

Hope I am adequately clear.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set them in setHTML `<b>hello world<b/>` is enough.

Also if you set the outer tags **you can't get them**, as they don't add anything in the formatting of the text.

Comment: The question if it's possible to get the "outer tags". There's no way to get them. No useful information is stored there.

Comment: He's obviously using this as a WYSIWYG editor, which offers a perfectly valid reason to want those extra tags. And see my answer for the way to get them that you claim doesn't exist.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but I think getText() returns the field without the tags. (Plain text)

Comment: Exactly.. as noted by Travis The purpose is to use it as a WYSIWYG editor. I have found a not so elegant intermediate solution, which works. But it would be nice if the outer html did not get stripped. user905374 for me the information IS important:-)

Comment: Exactly.. as noted by Travis The purpose is to use it as a WYSIWYG editor. I have found a not so elegant intermediate solution, which works. (For those interested I convert the head and body tags to be "comment tags" and reconvert them when I need them back to head and body tags.) But it would be nice if the outer html did not get stripped. user905374 for me the information IS important:-)